# Fill Consecutive NANs in a column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null, nan

I have a dataframe having a column C, I want to fill consecutive blanks by the same number because later I need to group that row.

eg

```
A B C
 1 2 Nan
 1 2 Nan
 1 2 3
 1 2 Nan
 1 2 Nan
```

the output I want is something like this

```
A B C
1 2 1
1 2 1
1 2 3
1 2 2
1 2 2
```

I tried using shift() to compare but didn't come to the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) by new `Series` created by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) by boolean `mask`:

```
df['C'] = df['C'].fillna(df['C'].notnull().cumsum() + 1)

print (df)
   A  B    C
0  1  2  1.0
1  1  2  1.0
2  1  2  3.0
3  1  2  2.0
4  1  2  2.0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['C'].notnull().cumsum())
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    1
Name: C, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 0):

The function fillna is your solution:

```
dataframe['yourColumn'] = dataframe['yourColumn'] .fillna( 1 , inplace=True)
```

Moreover you can put whatever value you want to substitute the nan values.
For instance, you coul set the mean:

```
dataframe['yourColumn']= dataframe['yourColumn'].fillna(dataset['yourColumn'] .mean(), inplace=True)
```

Comment: I want the consecutive NaNs to have the same number so the first consecutive Nan will have 1 the second consecutive Nan will have 2 and so on... Please read the question carefully